# How to get the path leading to given key / value in JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I looked around but didn't find a solution for this problem : 
I'm trying to get the full path (list of keys) leading to given key or value (taking into accounts dupes) .
I know its similar to this question : 
[how to get the path of an object's value from a value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996205/how-to-get-the-path-of-an-objects-value-from-a-value-in-javascript) 
But different in the way that you may find : 
- by key
- by value
- if any dupes are present, it should return an array of all possibilities
An short example being more speaking than a long speech :

Sample code :

```
var data = {
    "key1": {
        "key1SubKey1": {
            "key1SubSubKey1": "key1SubSubKey1_value"
        },
        "key1SubKey2": {
            "key1SubSubKey2": "key1SubSubKey2_value"
        },
        "key1SubKey3": {
            "key1SubSubKey3": "key1SubSubKey3_value"
        },
        "duplicatedKey": "duplicated_value"
    },
    "key2": {
        "key2SubKey1": {
            "key2SubSubKey1": "key2SubSubKey1_value"
        },
        "key2SubKey2": {
            "key2SubSubKey2": "key2SubSubKey2_value"
        },
        "key2SubKey3": {
            "key2SubSubKey3": "key2SubSubKey3_value"
        },
        "duplicatedKey": "duplicated_value"
    }
}
```

Usage example 
Search by value

```
getPathFromValue (data, "key2SubSubKey1_value") ;
// This should return : data['key2']['key2SubKey1']['key2SubSubKey1']

getPathFromValue (data, "duplicated_value") ;
// [ data['key1']['duplicatedKey'], data['key2']['duplicatedKey'] ]
```

Search by key

```
getPathFromKey (data, "key2SubSubKey1") ;
// data['key2']['key2SubKey1']

getPathFromKey (data, "duplicatedKey") ;
// [ data['key1'], data['key2'] ]
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: So far I have this http://jsfiddle.net/u2dK3/ which most certainly can be improved ;) .
I only get the path from values, not from the keys yet...

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
    function findValue(data, value,path){
    if(typeof(data) != "object" || Object.keys(data).length == 0) 
        return { "path" : "" , "value" : ""};

    for(var prop in data)  { 
     if (data[prop] == value) 
        return { "path" :  path + "['" + prop + "']" , "value" : value};
    }


    for(var prop in data) { 
        var result = findValue(data[prop],value,path === undefined ? "['" + prop + "']" : path + "['" + prop + "']" );

        if (typeof(result) !== typeof(undefined) && result.value != "") { 
            return result; 
        }
    }
}
```

execution of var result = findValue(data,"key1SubSubKey1_value") will result with an object with properties: value and path.

to get the path just access result.path.

Comment: `var thePath = findValue(data,"key2SubSubKey3_value") ;`
Gives me : InternalError: too much recursion ?

Comment: did you try it on the data object you posted here? i tried it again and it works perfectly. the error sounds like it iterates on an object with more levels.

Comment: At mine : 
• This works :
`var thePath = findValue(data,"key1SubSubKey1_value")`
• And this doesnt :
`var thePath = findValue(data, 'key2SubSubKey1_value') ;`
`var thePath = findValue(data,"key2SubSubKey3_value")`
On Chrome I get : "`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`"