# Deep find in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I want to be able to find the keyPath for a deeply nested value in Immutable.js. How could I fill out this function `deepFind` to get what I want?

```
const map = Immutable.fromJS({
    a: { 
        a1: 1,
        b1: 2
    },
    b: {
        b1: 3
        b2: 4,
        b3: 5
    }
});

function deepFind(map, value) {
    /* ??? */
}

deepFind(map, 4); // returns ['b', 'b2']
```

Comment: Run through the keys of map, check if each key's value === value, if it is, return `[key, map[key]]`, else check if `map[key]` is an object, if it is, call `deepFind(map[key],value)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996205/how-to-get-the-path-of-an-objects-value-from-a-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's any built-in way to do this, so I decided to go with a depth-first search. I used `.toKeyedSeq()` to search through all the collection types with the same code.

NOTE: This function will hang forever if your collections contain themselves.

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

function deepFind(root, value, path = Immutable.List()) {
  if (root === value) {
    return path;
  }

  if (!Immutable.isImmutable(root)) {
    // this is a leaf node, and it's not the value we want.
    return undefined;
  }

  for (const [key, child] of root.toKeyedSeq()) { 
    const result = deepFind(child, value, path.push(key));
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }

  // no path is found
  return undefined;
}
```